# Django PostgreSQL query that select objects where JsonField dicts have all a certain key set

Tags: django, postgresql

My model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Image(models.Model):
    tags = JSONField(null=False, blank=True, default={})
```

tags field value can be empty, or something like:

```
[
   {"tag": "xxx", "invalid": "true"}, 
   {"tag": "yyy"},
   {"tag": "zzz"}
]
```

I need to make a query that gives me Image objects where **all** objects in `tags` column have the "invalid" key set "true".

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `contains` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains):

```
Image.objects.filter(tags__contains=[{'invalid': 'true'}])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: With Image.objects.filter(tags__contains=[{'invalid': 'true'}]) works, but not returns Images with all invalid, but at least one

Comment: @user1518217 can you give examples of what should work and what should not?

Comment: Correct:
[
   {"tag": "xxx", "invalid": "true"}, 
   {"tag": "yyy", "invalid": "true"},
   {"tag": "zzz", "invalid": "true"}
]

No
[
   {"tag": "xxx", "invalid": "true"}, 
   {"tag": "yyy"},
   {"tag": "zzz"}
]

Comment: @user1518217 can you try `Image.objects.filter(tags__invalid='true')`?

Comment: It's not correct because json data it's not an object, but a list of objects